# Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-5.0

I have a requirement where I need to run a JS file to get a token. The JS file has references to variables like "window", "setTimeout" functions which are available when the browser loads.

But I need to load this load this Jmeter, and extract the token. Problem is JSR233 says it has no reference to "window" or "setTimeout" functions (which otherwise was available in the browser).

And when I run it, I get the below error. Is there any way that we can get a handle to these functions in Jmeter.

> 021-06-24 13:11:08,246 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in
> JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException:
> ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined in
> /Users/pprabhak/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BehaviorAnalytics-2.2.0.min.js
> at line number 12 javax.script.ScriptException: ReferenceError:
> "setTimeout" is not defined in
> /Users/pprabhak/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BehaviorAnalytics-2.2.0.min.js
> at line number 12     at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:477)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:433)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine$3.eval(NashornScriptEngine.java:521)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> javax.script.CompiledScript.eval(CompiledScript.java:89)
> ~[java.scripting:?]   at
> org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:217)
> ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.1]    at
> org.apache.jmeter.protocol.java.sampler.JSR223Sampler.sample(JSR223Sampler.java:72)
> [ApacheJMeter_java.jar:5.4.1]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.doSampling(JMeterThread.java:638)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:558)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]     at
> org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256)
> [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
> [?:?] Caused by: jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAException:
> ReferenceError: "setTimeout" is not defined   at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.error(ECMAErrors.java:57)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:319)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ECMAErrors.referenceError(ECMAErrors.java:291)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.**noSuchProperty**(Global.java:1616)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$21736$268435452$BehaviorAnalytics_2_2_0_min$cu10$restOf.VAAP$:split-2(/Users/pprabhak/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BehaviorAnalytics-2.2.0.min.js:12)
> ~[?:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$17386$73052$BehaviorAnalytics_2_2_0_min.VAAP(/Users/pprabhak/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BehaviorAnalytics-2.2.0.min.js:1)
> ~[?:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$17388$BehaviorAnalytics_2_2_0_min$cu1$restOf.:program(/Users/pprabhak/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/BehaviorAnalytics-2.2.0.min.js:1)
> ~[?:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:655)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:513)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:527)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.evaluateSource(Context.java:1438)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.Context.load(Context.java:962)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.objects.Global.load(Global.java:1720)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.scripts.Script$Recompilation$17383$^eval_/0x0000000800b68040.:program(:3)
> ~[?:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunctionData.invoke(ScriptFunctionData.java:655)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptFunction.invoke(ScriptFunction.java:513)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.internal.runtime.ScriptRuntime.apply(ScriptRuntime.java:527)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    at
> jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.evalImpl(NashornScriptEngine.java:428)
> ~[jdk.scripting.nashorn:?]    ... 9 more 2021-06-24 13:11:08,249 INFO
> o.a.j.t.JMeterThread: Thread is done: Thread Group 1-1

Comment: This may be because JMeter JSR 223 Sampler is not a web browser environment. Objects like `window` are exposed by browser

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) object is something closely related to the web browser, you won't be able to use in in JSR223 Test Elements.

There are 2 ways of handling this:

1. Use [WebDriver Sampler plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-webdriver-sampler) which:

   - has possibility to execute JavaScript via [JavascriptExecutor](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/JavascriptExecutor.html)
   - store the result into [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) via `WDS.vars` shorthand to [JMeterVariables](https://jmeter.apache.org/api/org/apache/jmeter/threads/JMeterVariables.html) class instance
2. Replicate the logic of the JavaScript file in the JSR223 Test Element (be aware that [Groovy language is recommended for scripting](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting)), if the script requires some parameters you should be able to get them from the previous response using JMeter's [Post-Processors](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#postprocessors)

Comment: Thank you I will check this

Comment: I am new to JS and hence please let me know if the below would be a valid statement. ```WDS.vars.put('VAAP', "/Users/<user>/performance/apache-jmeter-5.4.1/bin/Analytics-2.2.0.min.js")```

Comment: I can "load" to load this JS. but I end in the same problem saying "window" is not available.